# Form Validation in IE8 using Angular UI & webshims

Tags: angularjs, validation, internet-explorer-8, angular-ui, webshim

I am using webshims for HTML support in IE8. My HTML form validation is working in IE8. But when I have a form in a popup (I am using Angular UI Modal), on form submit(ng-submit) the modal box closes and the validation message appears on top right corner.

My Environment is

- jquery-1.11.1.js
- AngularJS v1.2.26
- Angular UI Modal 0.10.0
- webshim-1.15.4

In the console I get this script error

"invalid element seems to be hidden. Make element either visible or use disabled/readonly to bar elements from validation. With With fieldset[disabled] a group of elements can be ignored! In case of select replacement see shims/form-combat.js to fix issue."

part my Angular app HTML loading webshims

```
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>

<script>
    $.webshims.setOptions('forms', {
        overrideMessages : true
    });
    $.webshims.setOptions({
        waitReady : false
    });
    $.webshims.polyfill();
</script>


// below method in angular app to update Polyfill when dynamic view loads.

angular.module('essApp').run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {       
        $('body').updatePolyfill();
    });
});
```

My angular function to call a popup/modal

```
$scope.showGoalDetail = function(index) {
                $log.info('index is', index);
                $log.info('goal is', $scope.goals.goalList[index]);
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl : 'org/goalDetailPopUp.html',
                    controller : 'PopUpInstanceCtrl',
                    size : 'lg',
                    backdrop : 'static',
                    resolve : {
                        valueObject : function() {
                            var valueObject = new Object();
                            valueObject.goal = {};
                            angular.copy($scope.goals.goalList[index], valueObject.goal);
                            valueObject.kpiList=$scope.goals.kpiList;
                            return valueObject;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

My form in Modal Window

```
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #428bca; color: #FFFFFF">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Goal Detail</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <p class="panel-title">Administration of prespective and priority</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="ok()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Dimension</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required disabled ng-model="valueObject.goal.perspectiveDesc">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Key PerformanceIndicator</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" required ng-model="valueObject.goal.keyPerformanceIndicator"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"></div>
```

I need the validations to appear properly on popup next to the field

Comment: Could you provide some of the code that you are using? That way we can help you determine where the problem is.

Comment: @SamHuckaby I have update the post with code. I also found that I get script error (updated the post) thanks